# Cross Data Center: MySQL Replication vs Simple File Copying?

Tags: mysql, failover

Does it make sense to simply copy the mysql\data files vs mysql replication between data centers? I am having the impression mysql replication might be complex when done cross data center. And if I just copy, I could easily switch to the other data center w/o worrying if it's primary or slave. Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data centers? If you don't do replication you're going to have inconsistent/old data on switchover.

Comment: @KernelM I am trying data center failover so if DC1 fails I can just switch to DC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL with InnoDB storage engine uses multiversioning of the rows. This means there are changes to the database that may not be yet commited (and possibli will be reverted!). If you simply copy the files, you will end up in inconsistent state.

If you are using MyISAM, copying the files is safe. Replication hovewer will transfer only the changes, while copying will transfer the entire database each time. Which is not wise with large databases.

Comment: Well I didn't thought about Innodb and you right about non-committed rows. So I guess the other solution is to copy an SQL dump (and import), I believe dump contains only committed rows?

Comment: It is possible to make a consistent InnoDB (almost) hot backup, but you have to be very careful. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/21/using-lvm-for-mysql-backup-and-replication-setup/

Answer (score 0):

Replication synchronizes database between data centers "live".
While coping whole database takes a lot of time and databases will desynchronize after first change is made.